# Make dialog smaller on screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment

I want my dialog to not fit the whole screen like the image shown. How should i make it so it is not as long (height).[image]

```
public class SidemenuInfoDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.sidemenu_info_main, container, true);
        return layout;
      }

       @Override
       public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         Dialog dialog = new Dialog(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_Window_NoMinWith));
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            return dialog;
          }


}
```

**The View:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:id="@+id/sidemenu_info_main_relative">


            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/text1"
                    android:text="TEST TEXT "/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know if there is something else needed to be able to help me get on the right path of fixing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing you xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/sidemenu_info_main_relative">


        <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:text="TEST TEXT "/>

     </RelativeLayout>
```

If that does not work with you here is another approach that I usually do :

```
public class PopUp {
public  void poupUP(final Activity activity) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity, R.style.dialogwithoutTitle);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new      ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
     //here add the layout
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.pop_up);
   // The comments are to change the position of the alert dialogu
   // WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    //wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.END;
    //wmlp.x = 100;   //x position
    //wmlp.y = 100;   //y position


    dialog.show();
}
```

}

Then wherever you want it to show do this :

```
PopUp p = new PopUp();
p.popUP();
```

Comment: @Miriana Itani do not give fixed values for height and width as you don't know the size of your text  (your content )and these tends to vary on different devices.If a text is larger in size then it may cross well over 100 dp of your space.Instead use wrap_content.

Comment: @AnirudhSharma I just gave an answer as an example. I know how to deal with height and width. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Give your textview inside your dialog view height and width as **"wrap_content"**.Like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/sidemenu_info_main_relative">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:text="TEST TEXT "/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.sidemenu_info_main, container, false);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alert.getWindow().setLayout(dialogWidth, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
layoutParams.copyFrom(alert.getWindow().getAttributes());
layoutParams.x = xPosition;
layoutParams.y = yPosition;
alert.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```